# Can we use SEM for doing ANOVA?

Tags: anova, categorical-data, structural-equation-modeling

I am studying the influence of gender on the attribution of motives in romantic relationships. IV= Gender; DV= Love Motive. The analysis can be done using a one-way ANOVA. I was wondering if the same could be done using SEM (CB-based or variance based).
`Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ANOVA can be thought of as a kind of regression.
Regression can be thought of as a kind of SEM (using maximum likelihood, rather than OLS).

The model would be (in Lavaan syntax):

```
loveMotive ~ gender
```

If you use a robust estimator, your standard error will match the Welch (equal variances not assumed) t-test. Alternatively, you can use a multiple groups model. If you do constrain the variances to equality, you get the regular t-test, if you don't, you get the robust (Welch) t-test.

Comment: The answer is not general ; it works only if the predictor variable, here gender, has only two levels. What would be relation if gender has more than 2 levels???

Comment: Then you dummy code the predictor variable, just like regression.